# Using of fold expression to read csv file

Tags: c++, c++17

I've written a code reading csv file using fold expressions.
The only thing that should be defined is columns types and file name:

```
template <typename ...T, std::size_t... Is>
void parseLineToTuple(std::tuple<T...>& empty, const std::string& line, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    (ss >> ... >> std::get<Is>(empty));
}

template <typename ... T>
std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> readTuples(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> lines;
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            std::tuple<T...> empty;
            parseLineToTuple(empty, line, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
            lines.push_back(empty);
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

To use it:

```
auto content = readTuples<std::string, int, double>("lines.csv");
```

lines.csv:

```
apple, 20, 10.54
orange, 30, 4.5
```

Is it possible to get index sequence another way than passing it to a method and get the received parameter type? If so I would get rid of the *parseLineToTuple* method

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to determine whether the function succeeded or not.  Callers can't even inspect the the input stream afterwards, because it's local to the function.

If it's supposed to throw an exception when `open()`, `getline()` or `>>` fails, then we need to add

```
 file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit|std::ifstream::badbit);
```

We'll need to do that between creating the stream and opening the file:

```
std::ifstream file();
file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit|std::ifstream::badbit);
if (!file.open(fileName)) {
    throw std::ios_base::failure("open");
}
```